# table alternative in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an existing website for which I have to make an Android application. I have something a table with multiple `columns(20)` on the dashboard of website.
What will be an appropriate option to implement this? The screenshot of the table : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6SgMBRKkQ60WHB3bFc4Z2Y2cWM/view?usp=sharing

I had a look at `TableLayout`, but that might make the app look a little clumsy. Also, I learnt about horizontal `ListView`. Will that be a better option?

Comment: Vrinda, can you please post a screenshot of how you like to show it please?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking? Can you update the question.

Comment: @pratt not enough reputation to post an image.

Comment: Upload screenshot somewhere and share the link here.

Comment: @dhuma1981 have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with GridLayout.

http://androidexample.com/Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=75&aaid=99

above is reference for GridLayout.
and this is official android blog spot link for GridLayout.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom list view Or  a GridView
Good examples to begin are below:

http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76&aaid=100